# angular ngFor: How to differentiate default value from others

Tags: html, css, ngfor

I am using ngFor for a dropdown UI element. In dropdown,first entry is for conveying message(like, "Please select country") and rest are the values user need to select.

I want that first entry is a bit different in appearance form rest, like grayed out.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

app.component.html

```
<div> Months :
   <select (change) = "changemonths($event)" name = "month">
          <option class="default-select" disebled>--select--</option>
      <option *ngFor = "let i of months">{{i}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
.default-select{
background-color:gray;
}
```